# read urls from a text file

Tags: python, text, beautifulsoup

hello guys I want to put more URL on a text file and read them 1 by 1 with the code below
I want to open urls links from a text file, i want to run the script to extract data from 10 links for example not only from 1 how is the code created
Thank you so much for help

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

final_data = []
url = "https://denver.craigslist.org/search/cto?purveyor-input=owner&postedToday=1"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
get_details = soup.find_all(class_="result-row")

for details in get_details:
    getclass = details.find_all(class_="hdrlnk")
    for link in getclass:
        link1 = link.get("href")
        sublist = []
        sublist.append(link1)
        final_data.append(sublist)
print(final_data)

filename = "link.txt"
with open("./"+filename, "w") as csvfile:
    csvfile = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ",")
    csvfile.writerow("")
    for i in range(0, len(final_data)):
        csvfile.writerow(final_data[i])
```

Comment: The question is not clear, can you add some info?

Comment: yes, i want to open urls links from a text file, i want to run the script to extract data from 10 links for example not only from 1 how is the code created

Comment: put everything from the existing code (except imports) into a function that takes `url` and `filename` as arguments, outside the function: have a list of urls and output filenames, loop over the list and call your function for each url and filename

Comment: you can make an example please

Comment: if you want to use urls from file then just do it. `open()` file, and `read()` all text and later `split("\n")` to list of lines. And later use `for`-loop to run your code for different urls.

Comment: `writerow` is for writing list of data, not to write string.  `writerow( [""] )` . If you will use `string` then it may treat it as list fo chars and `writerow("Hello")` will write as `H,e,l,l,o`

Comment: simpler will be to use `writerows` with `s` at the end - which write all sublists as separated rows. It means `csvfile.writerows(final_data)`  without `for`-loop

Comment: if you have to use `for`-loop then it would be more readable `for row in final_data:         csvfile.writerow(row)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have every url in new line then simply open file, read all text and split on `\n` to get list of lines (without (`\n`))

```
with open('input.txt') as fh
    text = fh.read()
    all_links = text.split('\n')
```

or shorter

```
with open('input.txt') as fh
    all_links = fh.read().split('\n')
```

---

And later you have to use `for`-loop to run code for all urls

```
# - before loop -

final_data = []

# - loop -

for url in all_links:

    # ... code ...

# - after loop -

print(final_data)

# ... write in csv ...
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# - before loop -

#all_links = [
#    "https://denver.craigslist.org/search/cto?purveyor-input=owner&postedToday=1",
#]

with open('input.txt') as fh:
    all_links = fh.read().split('\n')

final_data = []

# - loop -

for url in all_links:
    print('url:', url)
    
    response = requests.get(url)
    #print('[DEBUG] code:', response.status_code)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    all_rows = soup.find_all(class_="result-row")

    for row in all_rows:
        all_links = row.find_all(class_="hdrlnk")
        for link in all_links:
            href = link.get("href")
            final_data.append( [href] )
            print('   >', href)
            
    print('----------')
    
# - after loop -

#print(final_data)

filename = "output.csv"   # no need to add `./` 

with open(filename, "w") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=",")
    csv_writer.writerow( ["links"] )
    csv_writer.writerows( final_data )  # with `s` at the end
```